# Geoprocessing in violated convention environments (Microsoft Windows)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, mapinfo, naming-conventions

Our MapInfo and ArcGIS users have self managed file shares. I do my best to educate our users about windows naming conventions but years of violating basic conventions and personalities that don't like conventions have made things difficult.

I have written a python crawl script that crawls a parent folder and all subsequent children folders while looking for and summarizing vector and raster data; projection names, feature counts, repair geometry count, etc.  The tool works perfectly in most locations.

**Geoprocessing** and crawls unfortunately **error** in deep deep folders that **violate Microsoft Windows total character counts**, and sometimes where characters break naming conventions.

**Are there ArcPy / Python / Desktop workflows to account for violations in MS Windows naming conventions?**

```
    import arcpy
    import os
    import math
    import numpy as np
    import sys
    from time import strftime
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
    ComputerName =os.getenv('COMPUTERNAME')


    arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
    arcpy.AddMessage("===================================================================")
    arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
    arcpy.AddMessage(" VERSION 5: SUMMARISE FOLDER: VECTOR & RASTERS")
    arcpy.AddMessage("  Data Walk: Listings Rasters & Feature Classes")
    arcpy.AddMessage(" ")


    FolderOrWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    ReportFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    txtRasterFile = open(ReportFolder+"\\" +"FullRasterReport.csv","w")
    txtVectorFile = open(ReportFolder+"\\" +"FullVectorReport.csv","w")
    State =" "
    txtFile2 = open(ReportFolder+"\\" +"SumReport.csv","w")
    TempFolder = os.path.join(ReportFolder,"Temp")
    TempFolderName ="Temp"

    if arcpy.Exists(TempFolder):
        print "ok"
    else:
        arcpy.CreateFolder_management(ReportFolder, TempFolderName)



    #txtFile.write ('\n')
    #txtFile.write ("===================================================================")
    #txtFile.write ('\n')
    #txtFile.close()

    txtRasterFile.write ("Time,Folder,Type,BandCount,RasterCompression,RasterFormat,SpatialRef,ReferenceType,Count")
    txtVectorFile.write ("Time,FullPath, FeatureClass,DataType, ShapeType, GDBFD, GDBFDN, SpatialRef,SpatialType,FeatureCount, RepairGeometry,GeomErrorCount,FieldCount,FeatureClassCount, ComputerName")
    txtFile2.write ("Time,RasterCount,VectorCount")

    gdbignore = ".gdb"
    RasterCount = 0
    FeatureClassCount = 0
    FeatureDataSetCount = 0


    DirList = []
    DirList.append(FolderOrWorkspace) #ADDS PARENT FOLDER TO LIST
    DataList = []
    VectorList = []
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(FolderOrWorkspace):
        #arcpy.AddMessage("   PREPROCESSING WALK: "+str(dirname))
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            if gdbignore in str(subdirname):
                print "ignore"
                #arcpy.AddMessage("    " + str(subdirname) +" is .gdb")
            else:
                #arcpy.AddMessage("    " + str(subdirname) +" is not .gdb")
                DirVar = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
                DirList.append(DirVar)

    for a in DirList:
        arcpy.AddMessage("     Processing Folder: "+str(a))
    del a
    DirListLen = len(DirList)

    arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
    arcpy.AddMessage(" -----------------------------------------------------")
    arcpy.AddMessage(" ")

    wsl = 0
    for fdir in DirList:
        wsl = wsl+1
        arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
        arcpy.AddMessage(" -----------------------------------------------------")
        arcpy.AddMessage("   WORKSPACE LOOP: "+str(wsl) + " of " +str(DirListLen))
        arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
        arcpy.env.workspace = fdir

        arcpy.AddMessage(" RASTER PROCESSING")
        RasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("*","")
        Rlen = len(RasterList)
        if Rlen == 0:
            arcpy.AddMessage( "   There are no rasters in: "+str(fdir))
        else:
            for raster in RasterList:
                RasterCount = (RasterCount +1)
                txtRasterFile.write ('\n')
                arcpy.AddMessage("       - RASTER:" + str(RasterCount) +" Name: "+raster +" Within: "+subdirname)
                txtRasterFile.write ((strftime("%d")+ " "+strftime("%b")+ " "+strftime("20%y")+ " "+strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
                txtRasterFile.write (","+subdirname + ",Raster,"+raster+",")


                desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)
                SR = desc.spatialReference
                try:
                    arcpy.AddMessage("         - Band Count:        %d" % desc.bandCount)
                    txtRasterFile.write (desc.bandCount+",")
                except:
                    arcpy.AddMessage("         - Does Not Support Bands")
                    txtRasterFile.write ("Unsupported,")
                try:
                    arcpy.AddMessage("         - Compression Type:  %s" % desc.compressionType)
                    txtRasterFile.write (desc.compressionType+",")
                except:
                    arcpy.AddMessage("         - Does Not Support Compression")
                    txtRasterFile.write ("Unsupported,")
                try:
                    arcpy.AddMessage("         - Raster Format:     "+desc.format)
                    txtRasterFile.write (desc.format+",")

                except:
                    arcpy.AddError("          - Raster Format: Error") #Error Message
                    txtRasterFile.write ("Error,")

                arcpy.AddMessage("         - Spatial Reference: "+SR.name)
                txtRasterFile.write (SR.name+",")
                arcpy.AddMessage("         - Reference Type:    "+SR.type)
                txtRasterFile.write (SR.type+","+str(RasterCount))

                arcpy.AddMessage(" ")

        arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
        arcpy.AddMessage(" VECTOR PROCESSING")



    ######## VECTOR
        ShpFcList = []

        ### FOR SHAPEFILES IN FOLDERS
        arcpy.AddMessage("    SHAPEFILE PROCESSING")
        Shapefilevectorlist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','All','')
        ShapeLen = len(Shapefilevectorlist)

        if ShapeLen == 0:
            arcpy.AddMessage( "      There are no shapefiles in: "+str(fdir))
        else:
            arcpy.AddMessage( "      There are " +str(ShapeLen) +" shapefiles in: "+str(fdir))
            for Shapefilevector in Shapefilevectorlist:
                DesShapefilevector = arcpy.Describe(Shapefilevector)
                DesShapefilevectorPath = DesShapefilevector.catalogPath
                arcpy.AddMessage( "        Feature class name: "+str(Shapefilevector))
                ShpFcList.append(DesShapefilevectorPath)

        ### FOR GEODATABASE IN FOLDERS
        eGDBList = []
        eGDBsfc =[] # to store fc

        arcpy.AddMessage("    GDB WORKSPACE PROCESSING")


        AcGDBList = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("", "Access")
        AcGDBListLen = len(AcGDBList)
        if AcGDBListLen == 0:
            arcpy.AddMessage( "      There are no access geodatabase in: "+str(fdir))
        else:
            arcpy.AddMessage( "      There are "+str(AcGDBListLen)+ " access geodatabase in: "+str(fdir))
            for AcGDB in AcGDBList:
                eGDBList.append(AcGDB)
        FiGDBList = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("", "FileGDB")
        FiGDBListLen = len(FiGDBList)
        if FiGDBListLen == 0:
            arcpy.AddMessage( "      There are no file geodatabase in: "+str(fdir))
        else:
            arcpy.AddMessage( "      There are "+str(FiGDBListLen)+ " file geodatabase in: "+str(fdir))
            for FiGDB in FiGDBList:
                eGDBList.append(FiGDB)

        eGDBLen = len(eGDBList)
        if eGDBLen == 0:
            arcpy.AddMessage( "      There are no geodatabase in: "+str(fdir))
            arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
        else:
            arcpy.AddMessage( "      There are " +str(eGDBLen) +" geodatabase in: "+str(fdir))
            arcpy.AddMessage(" ")

    ###################### MASTER LOOP
            for Gdbstet in eGDBList:
                arcpy.AddMessage("         " +str(Gdbstet))
            arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
            del Gdbstet
            WorkSpaceCnt = 0
            for Gdbs in eGDBList:
                WorkSpaceCnt = WorkSpaceCnt+1
                arcpy.AddMessage("    WORKSPACE ######## "+str(WorkSpaceCnt) + " of " +str(eGDBLen))

                try:
                    DenvGDB =  arcpy.Describe(Gdbs) #
                    envGDB = DenvGDB.catalogPath
                    arcpy.AddMessage("    " +str(envGDB))
                except Exception as e:
                    arcpy.AddError("       "+e.message)
                    if WorkSpaceCnt > eGDBLen:
                        arcpy.AddMessage( "CRITCAL " +str( WorkSpaceCnt) +" is > "+ str(eGDBLen))


                ### FOR STANDALONE FEATURE CLASS
                arcpy.AddMessage("        GDB STANDALONE FEATURE CLASS PROCESSING")
                envHold = arcpy.env.workspace
                arcpy.env.workspace = envGDB
                StandaloneFeatureClassList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','All','')
                StandaloneFeatureClassListLen = len(StandaloneFeatureClassList)
                if StandaloneFeatureClassListLen == 0:
                    arcpy.AddMessage( "              There are no stand alone feature class in: "+str(Gdbs))
                else:
                    arcpy.AddMessage( "              There are "+str(StandaloneFeatureClassListLen) +" stand alone feature class in: "+str(Gdbs))
                    for safc in StandaloneFeatureClassList:
                        Dessafc = arcpy.Describe(safc)
                        DessafcPath = Dessafc.catalogPath
                        arcpy.AddMessage( "              Feature class name: "+str(DessafcPath))
                        eGDBsfc.append(DessafcPath)
                    del safc, Dessafc, DessafcPath
                del StandaloneFeatureClassList

            ### FOR FEATURE DATASET FEATURE CLASS
                arcpy.AddMessage("        GDB FEATURE DATASET PROCESSING")
                FDS = arcpy.ListDatasets('','Feature')
                FDSTLen = len(FDS)
                if FDSTLen == 0:
                    arcpy.AddMessage("              There are no Geodatabase Feature Dataset in: "+str(envGDB))
                else:
                    arcpy.AddMessage("              There are " +str(FDSTLen) +" in Geodatabase Feature Dataset in: "+str(envGDB))
                    arcpy.AddMessage("          GDB FEATURE DATASET FEATURE CLASS PROCESSING")
                    FeatureDataSetCount = (FeatureDataSetCount+1)
                    for FDST in FDS:# FOR EVERY FD
                        FDFeatureClassList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','ALL',FDST) #ONLY X FEATURE DATA SET
                        FDFeatureClassListLen = len(FDFeatureClassList)
                        if FDFeatureClassListLen == 0:
                            arcpy.AddMessage( "                There are no Feature Class in the Feature Dataset in: "+str(FDST))
                        else:
                            arcpy.AddMessage( "                There are " +str(FDFeatureClassListLen) +" Feature Class in the Feature Dataset in: "+str(FDST))
                            for FDFC in FDFeatureClassList:
                                DesFDFC = arcpy.Describe(FDFC)
                                fdfcpath = os.path.join(DesFDFC.path, FDST, DesFDFC.BaseName) #idea
                                arcpy.AddMessage( "                Feature class name: "+str(FDST +"/"+ DesFDFC.BaseName))
                                eGDBsfc.append(fdfcpath)
                            del FDFC,DesFDFC,fdfcpath
                        del FDFeatureClassList
                    del FDST
                    #arcpy.AddMessage( " -")
                del FDS
                #arcpy.AddMessage( " --")
            # End of gdb loop
            envHold = arcpy.env.workspace
            #arcpy.AddMessage( " ---")


            ##### THE MAIN VECTOR PROCESS

            arcpy.AddMessage( " ")
            arcpy.AddMessage("    FEATURE CLASS PROCESSING: A")

            mainvList = []
            eGDBsfclen = len(eGDBsfc)
            if eGDBsfclen == 0:
                arcpy.AddMessage( "   There are no gdb Feature Class")
            else:
                for x in eGDBsfc:
                    mainvList.append(x)
                arcpy.AddMessage( "   There are "+ str(eGDBsfclen)+" gdb Feature Class")
                del x

            ShpFcListLen = len(ShpFcList)
            if ShpFcListLen == 0:
                arcpy.AddMessage( "   There are no Shapefile Feature Class")
            else:
                for x in ShpFcList:
                    mainvList.append(x)
                arcpy.AddMessage( "   There are "+ str(ShpFcListLen)+" Shapefile Feature Class")
                del x

            FullFCCnt = len(mainvList)
            if FullFCCnt == 0:
                arcpy.AddMessage( "   There are "+ str(FullFCCnt)+" Feature Class")
            else:
                arcpy.AddMessage("    FEATURE CLASS PROCESSING: B")
                arcpy.AddMessage( "   There are "+ str(FullFCCnt)+" Feature Class")
                arcpy.AddMessage(" ")


    ##            for Featuret in mainvList:
    ##                arcpy.AddMessage("     -: "+str(Featuret))
    ##            del Featuret

                arcpy.AddMessage(" ")

                for Feature in mainvList:
                    try:
                        desc = arcpy.Describe(Feature)
                        BaseName = desc.baseName
                        catalogPath = desc.catalogPath
                        path = desc.path
                        CheckOutTableName = os.path.join(TempFolder,"Check.dbf") #the repair reports
                        SR = desc.spatialReference
                        FeatureCount = arcpy.GetCount_management(Feature)
                        DataType = (desc.dataType)

                        FDNameT = "Stand Alone Feature Class"
                        FDSNE = 0
                        FeatureDataSetNameA = str(desc.path)

                        gdbignore2 = str(gdbignore+"\\")
                        if gdbignore2 in FeatureDataSetNameA:
                            FDNameT ="Feature Dataset Feature Class"
                            FeatureDataSetNameB = FeatureDataSetNameA.split(".gdb\\")[1]
                            FDSNE = 1

                        if FDSNE == 0:
                            FeatureDataSetNameB = "NA"

                    except Exception as e:
                        arcpy.AddError("       "+e.message)

                    try:
                        fieldsList = arcpy.ListFields(catalogPath,"","All")
                        fieldsListLen = len(fieldsList)
                    except Exception as e:
                        arcpy.AddError("       "+e.message)

                    ############## WRITE TO CSV FILE
                    FeatureClassCount = (FeatureClassCount +1)
                    txtVectorFile.write ('\n')
                    arcpy.AddMessage("         ========  ")
                    arcpy.AddMessage("         -FEATURE CLASS COUNT:"+str(FeatureClassCount) )
                    arcpy.AddMessage("         -"+str(catalogPath))

                    try: ### TIME
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - TIME--------------- " +str((strftime("%d")+ " "+strftime("%b")+ " "+strftime("20%y")+ " "+strftime('%H:%M:%S'))))
                        txtVectorFile.write ((strftime("%d")+ " "+strftime("%b")+ " "+strftime("20%y")+ " "+strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
                    except Exception as e:
                        arcpy.AddError("       "+e.message)

                    try: ### WORKSPACE ### NAME
                        #arcpy.AddMessage("         - PATH " + str(catalogPath))
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - FEATURE NAME------- " + str(BaseName))
                        txtVectorFile.write (","+catalogPath + ","+BaseName+",")
                    except Exception as e:
                        arcpy.AddError("       "+e.message)

                    try: ### DATA TYPE
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - DATA TYPE---------- "+DataType)
                        txtVectorFile.write (DataType +",")
                    except Exception as e:
                        txtVectorFile.write (DataType +",")

                    try: ### SHAPE TYPE
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - SHAPE TYPE--------- "+desc.shapeType)
                        txtVectorFile.write (desc.shapeType+",")
                    except Exception as e:
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - SHAPE TYPE--------- NON-STANDARD")
                        arcpy.AddError("         - : "+e.message)
                        txtVectorFile.write ("Non Standard,") #for the lack of a better word

                    try: ### STANDALONE?
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - STANDALONE--------- "+FDNameT)
                        txtVectorFile.write (FDNameT +",")
                    except Exception as e:
                        txtVectorFile.write (FDNameT +",")

                    try: ### STANDALONE NAME?
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - FEATURE DATASET---- "+FeatureDataSetNameB)
                        txtVectorFile.write (FeatureDataSetNameB +",")
                    except Exception as e:
                        txtVectorFile.write (FeatureDataSetNameB +",")



                    try: ### SPATIAL REFERENCE
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - SPATIAL REF-------- "+SR.name)
                        txtVectorFile.write (SR.name+",")
                    except Exception as e:
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - SPATIAL REF--------  ERROR")
                        arcpy.AddError("           - "+e.message)
                        txtVectorFile.write ("error,")#for the lack of a better word

                    try:
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - REFERENCE TYPE----- " +SR.type)
                        txtVectorFile.write (SR.type+",")
                    except Exception as e:
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - REFERENCE TYPE----- ERROR")
                        arcpy.AddError("         - : "+e.message)
                        txtVectorFile.write ("error,")#for the lack of a better word
                    try:
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - FEATURE COUNT------ "+str(FeatureCount))
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - FIELD COUNT-------- " +str(fieldsListLen))
                        txtVectorFile.write (str(FeatureCount)+",")
                    except Exception as e:
                        arcpy.AddError("       "+e.message)
                        txtVectorFile.write ("error,")#for the lack of a better word

                    try: #ISSUES
                        #arcpy.RepairGeometry_management(catalogPath, "DELETE_NULL" )
                        arcpy.CheckGeometry_management (catalogPath, CheckOutTableName)
                        MesseageText = arcpy.GetMessages(1)
                        ErrorCount = arcpy.GetCount_management(CheckOutTableName)

                        if str(ErrorCount) != "0":
                            arcpy.AddMessage("         - GEOMETRY CHECK----- There are : "+str(ErrorCount) +" errors" )
                            txtVectorFile.write ("geometry had errors ,"+str(ErrorCount)+",")
                            arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
                            arcpy.AddMessage(str(MesseageText))
                            arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
                        else:
                            arcpy.AddMessage("         - GEOMETRY CHECK----- Geometry is good" )
                            txtVectorFile.write ("geometry is good,"+str(ErrorCount)+",")
                            arcpy.AddMessage(" ")

                    except:
                        arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
                        #arcpy.AddError(e.message) # prints the error messages
                        arcpy.AddMessage("         - GEOMETRY CHECK----- Non standard geometry issue " )
                        txtVectorFile.write ("Non standard issue, #,")

                    try:
                        txtVectorFile.write (str(fieldsListLen)+",")
                        txtVectorFile.write (str(FeatureClassCount)+",")
                        txtVectorFile.write (str(ComputerName))
                        #txtVectorFile.write ('\n')
                    except Exception as e:
                        arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
                        arcpy.AddError(e.message) # prints the error messages

                    arcpy.AddMessage(" ")


    arcpy.AddMessage("===================================================================")
    txtRasterFile.close()
    txtVectorFile.close()

    txtFile2.write ('\n')
    txtFile2.write ((strftime("%d")+ " "+strftime("%b")+ " "+strftime("20%y")+ " "+strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
    txtFile2.write (","+str(RasterCount)+","+str(FeatureClassCount))
    txtFile2.close()
    if arcpy.Exists(TempFolder):
        arcpy.Delete_management(TempFolder)
```

I'm aware that when folders are too deep and the ArcGIS Desktop applications ArcMap and ArcCatalog can't work with the data; one method to address the issue is to use "Map Network Drive". However I can't conceptualize a way to use this in ArcPy.

How are you working with your GIS desktops clients and with code when you are hampered by naming convention violations?

Comment: If the path is too deep for the operating system, there isn't ***anything*** a mere application can do. This is really a management issue, for extreme sanctions on boys and girls who won't play nicely with the other children.

Comment: I've seen Arcpy fail to merge layers from different file geodatabases that can be viewed in ArcMap. Arcpy seems to have more path and name limitations than Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can circumvent the error of the deep deep folders / file path longer than 255 characters in two ways in Python.

One way is to use the `win32api` and get a short representation of the long filepath. From what I understand this is also what WinExplorer does internally.

```py
from win32api import GetShortPathName
long_path = "\\some\\really\\long\\.................path"

short_path = GetShortPathName(long_path)
```

The other way is to prefix the path with `\\?\`. I found this solution a while ago on one SE site and have no idea how or why it works but it does (at least on my systems).

```py
invalid_long_path = "C:\\some\\really\\long\\.................path"

valid_long_path = "\\?\C:\\some\\really\\long\\.................path""
```